# Why am I getting "UnboundLocalError local variable 'coffee_machine' referenced before assignment" despite coffee_machine being a global variable?

Tags: python, variables

```
coffee_machine = True

def user_input():
    while coffee_machine:
            user_choice = input("What type of coffee would you like espresso/latte/cappuccino?")
            if user_choice == "off".lower():
                coffee_machine = False
            x = []
            for ingredients in MENU[user_choice].get("ingredients").values():
                x.append(ingredients)
            print(x)

user_input()
```

Comment: You assign to `coffee_machine` with `coffee_machine = False` in the function and so you make it local.

Comment: Assigning to a variable inside of a function means that variable is treated as local, **even if** there is a global variable of the same name.  You have to specifically declare the variable as global.  Put `global coffee_machine` at the top of the function.

Comment: Even better: Don't use `global`. I don't see why it would be even needed here.

Comment: Side note: `"off".lower()` is useless, because `"off"` is obviously already lowercase.  I think you intended to call `.lower()` on the input variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared `global coffee_machine` at the start of the function, and thus it's not forced to be global, and within the function you try setting a value to it, which makes it local.
All that's needed to be done is adding that `global` line which will force it to be global, like so:

```py
coffee_machine = True

def user_input():
    global coffee_machine
    while coffee_machine:
            user_choice = input("What type of coffee would you like espresso/latte/cappuccino?")
            if user_choice == "off".lower():
                coffee_machine = False
            x = []
            for ingredients in MENU[user_choice].get("ingredients").values():
                x.append(ingredients)
            print(x)

user_input()
```